# How to send a video frame by frame from a Flask app to Flutter app

Tags: flutter, flask, video-streaming

I have to implement a video streaming functionality in Flutter.
The video will be stored in a back-end.
(Streaming as in how people can watch videos in YouTube, the video is fetched in real-time, as required).
How do I do this?
How can I alter the playback speed in the application and pause the video?

I watched a YouTube video on how to Stream a webcam using OpenCV and Flask but how can I do that with a video? [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vF9QRJwJXJk)
More importantly, how do I serve that to a Flutter app?

Comment: Any solutions to the question? What did you end up doing?